# Convert CSV stored in a string variable to table

Tags: sql, string, csv, variables, sql-server-2017

I've got CSV data stored in a string variable in SQL:

```
@csvContent = 
'date;id;name;position;street;city
 19.03.2019  10:06:00;1;Max;President;Langestr. 35;Berlin
 19.04.2019  12:36:00;2;Bernd;Vice President;Haupstr. 40;Münster
 21.06.2019  14:30:00;3;Franziska;financial;Hofstr. 19;Frankfurt'
```

What I want to do is to convert it to a #table, so it would look like

```
SELECT * FROM #table

 date                 id  name   position       street        city
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 19.03.2019  10:06:00 1   Max    President      Langestr. 35  Berlin
 19.04.2019  12:36:00 2   Bernd  Vice President Haupstr. 40   Münster
 21.06.2019  14:30:00 3   Franzi financial      Hofstr. 19    Frankfurt
```

The headers aren't fixed so the CSV could have more or less columns with differnt Header names.

I've tried it with `split_string()` and `pivot` but didn't find a solution for this.

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using. SQL Server, Oracle,...?

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server 2017

Comment: 1. By saying "the headers aren't fixed", do you mean that the table needs to be dynamically created?  2. Where did the string variable come from?--i.e., is there an underlying question of, say, how to load a CSV file into a table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: No the value comes from a stored procedure call with the string (CSV), BULK INSERT is not possible. Yes the table has to be dynamicly there could be more or less columns in the CSV

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server, this might be a solution for your request:

[How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: I already tried these Solutions but they all depend on fixed amount of column Headers which is not the case in my Problem here

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you

```
    CREATE TABLE #temp(
        date date,
        id int ,
        name varchar(100), 
       . ....... //create column that you needed
    )
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'BULK INSERT #temp
        FROM ''' + @CSVFILE+ ''' WITH 
        ( 
            FIELDTERMINATOR ='';'',
            ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'', 
            FIRSTROW = 2
         )';

        EXEC(@sql);

        SELECT *FROM #temp
        DROP TABLE #temp
```